# How to solve the screen resulution and booting problem of Ubuntu Linux system?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, suspend, display-resolution

Last night I switched off my computer, everything as usual, nothing special. The next day I start the computer via the button, it starts booting, BIOS starts, the Ubuntu boot window pops up, then a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top left corner, and then the computer idles. Booting through resume does work and Ubuntu loaded, but now there is a problem with the screen resolution. The whole interface became large and low quality, while in the settings screen resolution is 1024x768, this is the maximum, and the minimum 800x600. At that after switching off the computer and switching it on through the button I still have to enter BIOS and start it through resume. How can I fix the problem of booting the system at startup and set the normal screen resolution?

I tried to enter BIOS with the Esc key and restore the system with the resume command. I also tried to fix possible errors in the file system with the fsck command.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Comment: Sounds like video driver problems. What video card do you have? What video driver were you using?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 430]